# MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore vs Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

Which database connector should I use in **.Net Core 2** enterprise level web app which is going to handle large amount of data.

I have two choices:

1. Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql
2. MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore

But still confuse which one to choose for the development.

I started with **MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore**, which is MySQL official provider but after facing several issues while code first migration I had to google again for some better alternative.

After some research I found **Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql** bit more helpful for my application and it also covered the issues I was facing before.

But it still left me a bit confuse about which one to choose for long term.

**Pomelo** is workign fine currently but I am not sure if they (pomelo team) will keep always keep it updating and will keep it in sync with the latest .Net Core version available in the market??

**MySql** is not working as expected but the only plus point with this is : It is provided by MySQl itself.

Please help me to decide

Comment: I've observed that most people prefer Pomelo's. It has, so far, been more complete and up-to-date. This isn't an endorsement--just an observation. ;-)

Comment: Agree, one more thing I have noticed about Pomelo team is that they are very fast to respond any query on their GIT branch, I have experienced it 2-3 times.

Comment: Bad news from Pomelo team that they will not keep updating: https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/522

Comment: A direct quote from [Announcing Entity Framework Core 2.1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/05/30/announcing-entity-framework-core-2-1/) is _"We have been working and will continue to work with provider writers to make sure we identify and address any issues with the upgrade. In the particular case of Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql, we are actively working with the developers to help them get it ready for 2.1."_

Comment: I facing issues using both of them. So be aware, you can't be sure that tomorrow you will not find that something doesn't work. Pomelo has many open issues on github without fixes

Comment: Yes, but after working on it since 1 year I found Pomelo as better choice instead of MySQL default provider and haven't yet faced any bug or difficulty while using.

Comment: No worries, Pomelo's active development is continuing and we are the only community driven open source provider that released an EF Core 3.0 compatible provider so far (and the only MySQL provider because Oracle has not released one until now). We also have a very stable prerelease for EF Core 3.1 out already. As for bug fixing, we fixed most reported issues in our recent releases and react very quickly to reported issues. It is true however, that there was a phase with only little advancements, because we were looking for contributors. This is not the case anymore however.

Comment: Anyone have issues with MySqlConnection being ambiguous because we have other projects in the same solution that use the MySql.Data dll's for other reasons.

Comment: @LenardBartha MySqlConnector 1.0.0+ changed its namespace to be distinct from the one Oracle is using. Pomelo.EFCore.MySql 5.0.0+ will be based on that versions of MySqlConnector, so there should be no workarounds needed anymore in the future, in cases where MySqlConnector and MySql.Data are used in parallel.

Comment: @lauxjpn Yay, that is great news!